# VBScript VarType function gives weird value

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I've encountered a strange problem with getting data from a Database and casting it to the correct type using VBScript for ASP.

I have a recordset retrieved using the following function:

```
Public Function vfuncGetRS(strQuery)
    'Returns a disconnected paging capable recordset
    'Note - Non Windows servers don't support disconnected recordsets so you'll always get a connected recordset on
    '   a non Windows server!

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Clear

    Dim objData

    Set objData = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objData.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objData.CursorType = adOpenStatic
    objData.LockType = adLockReadOnly
    objData.Open vlogSQLFilter(strQuery), objDB

    If Not blnUNIXMode Then
        Set objData.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    End If

    Set vfuncGetRS = objData
End Function
```

If I select a value from the recordset and gets its VarType it returns the value 16 eg.

```
Set objRS = vfuncGetRS("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE")
Response.Write(VarType(objRS("someColumn")))
```

The weirdness is in two parts

1. This ONLY happens on a particular server, this code is part of a CMS which I deploy on multiple sites and it's only the instance running on IIS 6.0 that causes me an issue.  Also this seems to be dependent on the recordset options.
2. The value 16 is not a valid value for VarType to return according to the official MSDN reference

I can get round this fairly easily by adding a check to the function that is being affected by the weird values which is as follows

```
If VarType(strValue) = 16 Then strValue = CInt(strValue)
```

I have to do the above because I need the function in question to correctly detect that the type is numeric and if the VarType is 16 then IsNumeric() gives false even if the value in the variable is numeric (and it will always be numeric)

So my question is does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Question: When you get the VarType 16 what is the underlieing column data type?

What kind of database do you use?

All this affects the result of the VarType function.

Comment: The underlying column data type is BIT, the database can be Access, MySql 4x/5x or SQL Server 2000+.  As I said the software is installed on multiple servers in different environments.  This particular environment is IIS 6.0 using MySQL 4.1.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Stijn` have stated, the value of 16 means that it's a ***`One Byte Variant`***, specified in the [C++ headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) as `VT_I1`.

And you're only getting this value because of the MySQL connection driver (as you've stated that the environment where you encounter this 16 value is IIS6 with MySQL).

Apparently this is a bug in the MySQL driver that instead of reporting `adBoolean` for a BIT field it's Reporting `VT_I1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=nl&lr=&q=vartype%20VT_%20%3D16), 16 might stand for VT_I1, thus a single byte signed integer.